# Determine the direction of given parametrization.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, self-learning

I saw an example, which I posted below.

[image]

First of all, I understand how to show paramtrized curve but I dont understand how to determine the direction of the parametrization.

For example, how can I show the direction of the parametrization

$$\tilde{c}(t)=\langle rcost, -rsint \rangle$$ for $ t \in [-2\pi , 0]$

I know this question is so easy and basic, but I dont understand enough. I am greatful if someone explains this. Thank you

Comment: By the way, sorry I tried to make the sign "~" upper $c$

Comment: $\tilde{c}$? That's `$\tilde{c}$`. And use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<`, `>`.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do this. Thank you @DanielFischer.

Comment: Okay, I corrected all of them. @DanielFischer

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of answer you want. Is noting that when you look at the points for $T = -2\pi,\, t = -\frac{3\pi}{2},\, t = -\pi,\, t = - \frac{\pi}{2}$ you get $(r,0),\, (0, -r),\, (-r,0),\, (0,r)$ enough?